# How to correctly represent true / false when dealing with radio buttons?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to wrap my head around this and trying to improve my Javascript ability.  I am using ASP.NET Core MVC to create a basic web form and I've got Javascript that will run when a radio button is selected.

Razor

```
<div class="form-row">
            <div class="form-group col-sm-4">
                <label class="bold" asp-for="PhoneSetup"></label>
                <br />
                <input type="radio" asp-for="PhoneSetup" name="PhoneSetup" value="true" onclick="phoneSetupSelect()" /><label>Yes</label>
                <input type="radio" asp-for="PhoneSetup" name="PhoneSetup" value="false" onclick="phoneSetupSelect()" /><label>No</label>
            </div>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
<script>
    function phoneSetupSelect() {
        var formInput = document.getElementById("myForm");
        var phoneSetupValue = formInput.PhoneSetup.value;
        //alert(phoneSetupValue);
        console.log('phoneSetupValue = ' + phoneSetupValue);
        if (phoneSetupValue == 'true') {
            document.getElementById('hiddenDiv').classList.remove("hidden");
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById('hiddenDiv').classList.add("hidden");
        }
    }
</script>
```

Aside from the `if` condition shown in the script, I tried the following

`if(phoneSetupValue == true)` and `if(phoneSetupValue)`

with mixed results.  The former does not work, despite the model property being of type `bool` and the latter DOES work, which I understand why.  In that case, since the same script is attached to both radio buttons, the value being present on either will trigger the `true` condition.

I got it to work but I'm just confused as to why and if there are ways I can make this better and less "hacky" feeling.

Comment: You can set value as 1 or 0 instead and if condition check it as `if(phoneSetupValue*1 === 1)`

Comment: Check the `checked` property.  `if(phoneSetupValue.checked)`  https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-get-value-of-selected-radio-button-using-javascript/

Comment: You're comparing a boolean to a string with a shallow equals, which is not a good idea. true (type boolean) == 'true' (type string) will always return false.